# TemplateNotFound error when running simple Airflow BashOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to write our first Airflow DAG, and I'm getting the following error when I try to list the tasks using command `airflow list_tasks orderwarehouse`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 2038, in resolve_template_files
    setattr(self, attr, env.loader.get_source(env, content)[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: ./home/deploy/airflow-server/task_scripts/orderwarehouse/load_warehouse_tables.sh
```

This DAG is not supposed to use a template. I'm only trying to run the shell script in the specified location per the instructions in [the docs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/bash_operator.html#BashOperator). The shell script does exist in that location and is spelled correctly. My DAG looks like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

orderwarehouse = DAG('orderwarehouse', default_args=default_args)

load_mysql = BashOperator(
    task_id='load_warehouse_mysql',
    bash_command='./home/deploy/airflow-server/task_scripts/orderwarehouse/load_warehouse_tables.sh',
    dag=orderwarehouse)
```

Not sure why it thinks it needs to look for a Jinja template. Running out of ideas on this one, would appreciate if anyone can point me to where I'm going astray. Thanks.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This is a pitfall of airflow. Add a space at the end of your bash_command and it should run fine

Source:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62694614

Comment: Discovered it also works with a newline ahead of the filename!

Comment: Does this also apply if the command has args following it (eg. `bash /path/to/script.sh arg1 arg2 ...`)? The docs did not seem to indicate.

Comment: i think it does, however i haven't tested that.

Comment: If you look at the [BashOperator source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d719e1fd6705a93a0dfefef4b46478ade5e006ea/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L68), there's `template_ext = ('.sh', '.bash',)`. Any string ending with either of those values will be interpreted as a Jinja template file. There's also `template_fields = ('bash_command', 'env')` which is the list of fields this behavior applies to.

Comment: It's now 2020, how can this bug still be there?  I just spent hours tracking this down. :(

Comment: Its now 2021, and the bug still there

Comment: (Putting a note in my agenda for 1-jan-2022, 1 month from now, to make the next comment here...) :-)

Comment: placing semi colon (;) at the end of command also solve the problem

Comment: it is 2022 and the bug is still there and also applies to wherever you need to pass a file_path as a parameter

Comment: it is 2023 and the bug is still there

Comment: its 2023 October, and it still persists

Comment: Guys, this behavior will never be changed due to compatibility reason, unless they decide to do an Airflow 3. And even then, it's unlikely, because this is a KISS way to allow users to choose to between templating either the file path or the file content.

Comment: Would be mega nice if Apache would add at least a hint to the Exception text if they can't really change this behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

in addition to all the answers provided i had to do something more to get rid of the jinja template not found issue.

we have to add space after the file name in task definition.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should try with space at the end of filepath. whichever operator you are using you should always follow the same rule.

```
load_mysql = BashOperator(  
             task_id='load_warehouse_mysql',  
             command='/home/deploy/airflow-server/task_scripts/orderwarehouse/load_warehouse_tables.sh ',  
             dag=orderwarehouse)
```