# ERROR - Exception rendering Jinja template for task from BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

I've been getting this following issue, for the last couple of weeks out of no where.

> ERROR - Exception rendering Jinja template for task
> 'sometask', field 'sql'
>
> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:
> sql/test.sql

I have a task to execute a piece of sql through `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator`. This is how my task looks like

```
tt = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id="test1",
        sql=const.sqlfolder + "test.sql",
        destination_dataset_table="target_table",
    )
```

I also do have a `user_defined_macros` which i'm referring to in the SQL file.

```
user_defined_macros={
        "test_function": const.TEST_FUNCTION
}
```

and this is how i'm referring to it in the SQL file:

```
SELECT
    {{ test_function }} as test,
    *
FROM
    sometable
```

Airflow version that I'm using is `2.4.3`. I did go through some of the similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147514/templatenotfound-error-when-running-simple-airflow-bashoperator), but those seem not related to this at all. One was for `BashOperator` where we have to leave a space at the end of the path of the file or try using the variable through `Params` rather than macros.

This issue happens once in a while during daily runs.

Any help is really appreciated, if anyone has gone through the same.